# Intercepting response in dojo to read cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, dojo, widget

I have a filter on server side which adds a cookie `myCookie` to every response.

I am intercepting the response in a dojo widget as below:

```
define("mySolution/ServerCookieWidget", [
"dojo/request/notify",
"dojo/cookie"
], function (notify, cookie) {
notify("load", function(response) {
     var cookieRead = cookie("myCookie");
     console.log('Cookie read is: ', cookieRead);
    });
});
```

I want to use the value read to do some calculation on client side.

How do I share the read cookie value with other widget?

I am new to dojo and thus not aware of the syntax and not able to find any example for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the rest of your architecture, you might want to use Dojo's pubsub module `dojo/topic`:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/topic.html

So for example, changing your code to:

```
define("mySolution/ServerCookieWidget", [
    "dojo/request/notify",
    "dojo/cookie",
    "dojo/topic"
], function (notify, cookie, topic) {
    notify("load", function(response) {
        var cookieRead = cookie("myCookie");
        // console.log('Cookie read is: ', cookieRead);
        topic.publish("*/cookie/value", cookieRead);
    });
});
```

You can create widgets which subscribe to the topic:

```
define("mySolution/SomeOtherWidget", [
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/topic"
], function (declare, topic) {
    var OtherWidget = declare(null, {
        constructor: function (opt) {
           this.topicHandle = topic.subscribe("*/cookie/value", this._handleCookieValue.bind(this));
        },
        _handleCookieValue: function (cookieVal) {
            console.log("Cookie value is:", cookeVal);
        }
    });

    return OtherWidget;
});
```